# Is it necessary to use CodeIgniter in creating a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm creating a website and encounter `CodeIgniter` while searching for a tutorial. My question is "Is it necessary to use CodeIgniter in creating a website or using `PHP`, `HTML`, and javascript just fine?". Because I'm a beginner and I'm so confused if I have to use it or not.

Comment: It is not necessary to use codeigniter.

Comment: framework is not necessary, it will help you in some ready features that you can user, you can go with simple html , php and javascript foe website.

Comment: It is not neceessary at all. You can use any framework like laravel or anyother. Personally I like to work in laravel for projects as they give many predefined methods.That will ease my work.

Comment: Thank you for answering @DevsiOdedra and @Jaapaap! thumbs up to you two

Comment: I want to use that too @chaitanyaswami but I'm not knowledgeable enough to use that xD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Big thing and short thing NO. pleas read up on php https://www.learn-php.org/ maybe not the best site but it will get you started

Comment: thank you sir! I will look into it